# Mapbox with Xcode 7 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, mapbox, swift2

I'm trying to integrate [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com) with my project running on iOS 8 (and above), Xcode 7 beta 5 and Swift 2. I've followed the [provided instructions](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/first-steps-ios-sdk/). My Podfile:

```
target 'Project' do
platform :ios, '8.0'
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
use_frameworks!
end
```

On `pod install` everything integrates and is ok. But once I try to `import Mapbox` it shows me a compile error:

> No such module "Mapbox"

Pods seem to be properly integrated.

> Pod version: 0.37.0

[image]

I don't know why I can't import the Mapbox...

Please let me know if you're familiar with such issue.

Comment: "Expected expression after unary operator"

Doesn't work. :(

Comment: Sorry, use underscores: `import Mapbox_iOS_SDK`

Comment: Interesting... "Could not build Objective-C module 'Mapbox_iOS_SDK'" and "'RMAnnotation.h' file not found". All headers are marked as 'Public'.

Comment: Should should indeed now be fixed as of 2.0.0 (final) which addresses a bug in CocoaPods semantic versioning. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoapods/a3_iav-NuIg

Answer (score 0):

[Their API](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/)  was updated today and they are repackaging MapboxGL 0.5.1 as the Mapbox iOS SDK 2.0.0 series which is a prerelease.

I made the mistake of updating today and I'm having the same problem so we'll have to wait.

Comment: Wuh. Thank you @Andres! Have you faced the same problem before? Just wonder how long it might take... :)

Comment: Not sure. Try following the steps in the "First Steps Guide" you posted but add the "MapboxGL" pod instead of the "Mapbox-iOS-SDK" one.

Comment: @JAL Sorry. I was not able to post my "answer" as a comment before hand, because it was my first post.

Comment: Alright, it finally works! 2.0 version is stable now :)